# Projectile Motion Simulation in HTML5 JavaScript canvas

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

I'm looking to simulate projectile motion (off the ground with a certain velocity, continuing until the ball lands on the ground again) ignoring air resistance. I'm using the canvas feature of HTML5 and JavaScript to do it. I'm a novice with JavaScript, so any help is appreciated.

This is my code so far. I'm running into the same error again and again: unexpected end of input. I'm also trying to include start, stop, and reset buttons, as well as the option for the user to input their own angle, so they can see the final horizontal distance change.

I've tried many different ways to get rid of this error; what am I missing?

```
<html>

<head>
    <title>
    Projectile Motion
    </title>
</head>

<body>

<button onclick=settimer()>Start</button><br>
<button onclick=reset()>Reset</button><br>
<button onclick=cleartimer()>Stop</button><br>
Angle=<input type="text" id="Angle in Degrees" value=45></input>
<canvas id="mycanvas" height="600" width="600"></canvas>

<script>

function rectang() {
co.beginPath();
co.rect(0,0,600,600);
co.stroke();
}

var gravity
var Angle
var velocity
var velocityx
var velocityy
var distance
var co
var inc
var time
var x
var y
var radius



//list variables

function init() {
    var can;
    can = document.getElementById("mycanvas");
    co = can.getContext("2d");
    reset();
}

function reset() {
    gravity = 5;
    Angle = (45*(Math.PI)/180);
    velocity = 10;
    velocityx = velocity*Math.cos(Angle);
    velocityy = velocity*Math.sin(Angle);
    time = 0;
    distance = velocityx*time;
    inc = 0.5;
    x = 0;
    y = 600;
    radius = 10;
}

function draw() {
    co.clearRect(0,0,600,600);
    circle(co,x,y,radius,"yellow",false)

    time = time + inc;
    x = x + velocityx*time;
    y = y + velocityy*time;
    velocityx = velocityx;
    velocityy = velocityy + velocityy*time;
}


function settimer() {
    if (timer == null) timer = setInterval(draw,time);
    Angle = document.getElementById("Angle").value;
}
function cleartimer(){
    clearInterval(timer);
    timer = null;
}

init();


function circle(context,x,y,r,color,fill) {
    if (fill == true) {
        //if fill is true, fill the circle
        var temp = context.fillStyle;
        context.fillStyle = color;
        context.beginPath();
        context.arc(x,y,r,0,2*Math.PI);
        context.fill();
        context.fillStyle = temp;
    }
    else {
        //if fill is false, don't fill the circle
        var temp = context.strokeStyle;
        context.strokeStyle = color;
        context.beginPath();
        context.arc(x,y,r,0,2*Math.PI);
        context.stroke();
        context.strokeStyle = temp;
    }


</script>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: JavaScript is NOT Java.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: You are missing a closing } for the last function circle.

Answer (score 0):

There are some issues, mainly some kind of double-incrementing, where "time" was getting  larger each loop, and x/y values were incrementing itself too. Also, for "velocityy" you should rather use negative value at start (bullet getting higher) and then add something based on gravity. And yellow isn't very readable here.

```js
function rectang() {
co.beginPath();
co.rect(0,0,600,600);
co.stroke();
}

var gravity
var Angle
var velocity
var velocityx
var velocityy
var distance
var co
var inc
var time
var x
var y
var radius



//list variables

function init() {
    var can;
    can = document.getElementById("mycanvas");
    co = can.getContext("2d");
    reset();
}

function reset() {
    gravity = 5;
    Angle = (45*(Math.PI)/180);
    velocity = 10;
    velocityx = velocity*Math.cos(Angle);
    velocityy = velocity*Math.sin(Angle)*-1;
    time = 0;
    distance = velocityx*time;
    inc = 0.5;
    x = 0;
    y = 300;
    radius = 10;
}

function draw() {
//console.log(x,y)
    co.clearRect(0,0,600,300);
    circle(co,x,y,radius,"yellow",false)

    time = time + inc;
    x = x + velocityx*inc;
    y = y + velocityy*inc;
    velocityx = velocityx;
    velocityy = velocityy + gravity*inc*0.1;
}

var timer = null;
function settimer() {
    if (timer == null) timer = setInterval(draw,time);
    Angle = document.getElementById("Angle").value;
}
function cleartimer(){
    clearInterval(timer);
    timer = null;
}

init();


function circle(context,x,y,r,color,fill) {
x = Math.round(x)
y = Math.round(y)
//console.log(x,y,r,color,fill) 
    if (fill == true) {
        //if fill is true, fill the circle
        var temp = context.fillStyle;
        context.fillStyle = color;
        context.beginPath();
        context.arc(x,y,r,0,2*Math.PI);
        context.fill();
        context.fillStyle = temp;
    }
    else {
        //if fill is false, don't fill the circle
        var temp = context.strokeStyle;
       
        context.beginPath();
        context.arc(x,y,r,0,2*Math.PI);
        context.strokeStyle = color;
        context.lineWidth = 4;
        context.stroke();
        context.strokeStyle = temp;
    }
}
```

```html
<button onclick=settimer()>Start</button><br>
<button onclick=reset()>Reset</button><br>
<button onclick=cleartimer()>Stop</button><br>
Angle=<input type="text" id="Angle" value=45></input>
<canvas id="mycanvas" height="300" width="600"></canvas>
```